# Private chat with nodejs, php, expressjs?

Tags: node.js

I am doing a chat with these techonologies: NodeJS, PHP (for someother things), Express.JS

The chat will have private rooms. A private room is a private conversation, such as on Facebook chat. Let's say that a room is: `my.page/index.php?room=123`

1) How can I get the id of the room? (Which in this case is 123)

2) How can I manage all the messages sent on room = 123 to be kept on just that room?

Any other recommendation will be welcome!

Comment: Far too vague. What is a room exactly?

Comment: If you are using socket.io you might want to have a look at their [room API](https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io). And if you are not using socket.io, you should.

Comment: Yes, I am using it, but it still doesn't tell me how to fetch the room id from the url

Comment: @Ale Go download the IRC example from the socket.io repo linked. It includes joining and leaving chat rooms.

Comment: -4 and only one negative comment? c'mon. Pretty obvious he/she is new and might not have a complete grasp of the etiquette but you must if downvoted.

Comment: When I got time I would like to improve my code and push it to github. I think it can achieve everything you would like to achieve. But right now I am busy as hell :$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `$_GET['room']`

2) Your database where you store the messages would have a `room` column.

Comment: What about if I do not store the messages?

Comment: You still have a `room` property associated with each message and each connection waiting for messages.

Comment: Yes! From io, but how do I get the id from the url and pass it to server.js?

Comment: What's server.js? You've shared no code. We're in the dark. That's why your question has -3 votes and 2 votes to close.

Comment: I have no code to share, because I have the basics written on...see: http://pastebin.com/0KJv9Bjd

Comment: Then you're not far enough along to ask these questions. The only way to answer them would be to write the app for you... where it's already written in many socket.io examples. Once you've written the client side (where you can hard code a room number) you can share your PHP and JavaScript code and ask how to get the room number into the JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

To get id add next code to **server.js**:

```js
app.get('/room', function (req, res, next) {
  if ( req.query.room )
  {
    res.end(req.query.room);
  }
  else
  {
    res.end('List of public chats!...');
  }
});
```

Then you should process all incoming messages for the room

```js
app.post('/room/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  if ( req.body && req.body.message )
  {
    console.log(req.body.message); // Output your sent message
  }
  next();
});
```